# iPad changes to neighbors unsecured WiFi

Tags: ipad, network, wifi

My iPad frequently changes to the neighbors unsecured WiFi.  I have added my own WiFi extender to increase my WiFi signal strength in the room where I work but frequently find my iPad switching to the neighbor's WiFi.  I have connected to the neighbor's WiFi then "Forgotten" that network; however it frequently pops back on and replaces my own secured network connection.  Apple has been unable to provide a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Do you use a Mac which is logged into the same iCloud account as your iPad?

Comment: Thanks for your comment/question but there is no Mac in the house or on the network.  I have spoken with Apples reps and there seems to be no way to restrict the iPad to a preferred network.  Even when turning off the option to "ask to join a network".  Seems strange you cannot control/restrict the iPad to a specific network/WiFi connection.

Comment: Have you tried going to Settings > General > Reset and selecting Reset Network Settings?